# People and acquaintances - simple graph theoretical question

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have taken the following problem from an introductory text on graph theory. Somehow I am missing something about this problem, as the statement seems wrong to me.

> There is a group of $n$ people $A_1, \ldots,A_n$ in which some people
>   know each other and any two people who do not know each other would
>   have common acquaintance. Suppose that $A_1$ and $A_2$ know each other
>   but do not have common acquaintance. Show that the acquaintances of
>   $A_1$ are as many as those of $A_2.$

It is obvious how to model this question in the graph theoretical framework. What I am wondering is why isn't $P_3$ (picking a leaf and a 2-vertex for $A_1$ and $A_2$) a counterexample. The two leaf nodes do not know each other but have common friend, but $A_1$ and $A_2$ do not have the same number of acquaintances.

What am I missing?

Comment: Google told me that this question - with a solution - can be found in the book Graph Theory by Bin Xiong, Zhongyi Zheng on [page 5](http://books.google.com/books?id=FHkzyUeQ1MEC&pg=PA5). However, I still cannot find flaw in your counterexample, even after comparing it with their alleged proof. Perhaps they have forgotten to add some assumption?

Comment: You have found a counter-example, so what you have written here is wrong. For more guessing on the authors' intention, we would need more context.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658/i-have-found-an-error-in-a-book-paper-what-do-i-do

Answer (score 1):

From the link provided in the comment by Martin Sleziak, one can conclude from the proof that the authors wanted to demand that two nonadjacent vertices have *exactly two* common acquaintances.

Comment: I was just about to write a similar answer. (At least if Azoo has taken the problem from that book, it seems to be very reasonable conjecture.) Here's a [similar problem](http://www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/math/33592/discrete-math-with-difficult-party) - it also contains the condition that non-adjacent vertices have exactly two common neighbors.